# File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'san' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

This is my first experience with a programming language. I was executing this code in python and I got the error. please help me.

```
 print("welcome")
name=input("\nHi, What's your name ?")
age=input("\nHow old are you?")
weight=int(input("How many pounds do you weight?"))



   print("Hello,",name, "you are ", age, " years old. And you weigh ",weight," pounds")
```

Comment: when I entered the name 'san', it gave the following error:

File “<string>”, line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'san' is not defined

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure you are running with python 3.x?

This looks like a python2.x Error to me - running your Code under  python 3 Works like a charm.

If you replace input with raw_input it Works with 2.x as well

Comment: @OP: You can check the version you are running under with `import sys; print(sys.version)`